# Change color of jQuery Accordion header from data within its asp Repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery accordion that is inside an asp repeater with a template like so:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repAccordion" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h3 id="head">
                <span><%#Eval("value1") %>   <%#Eval("value2") %></span>
                <span class="status">Status: <%#Eval("statusValue") %></span>    
            </h3>
            <div></div>
        <ItemTemplate>
```

On most occasions, there should be multiple values in the accordion.  Is there a way that I could loop through and change the color of the header, based on the value of what's in the "statusValue" variable that's taken from the bound repeater data?  I'd like to color them based on 3 statuses.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you have a CSS class based on the status, rather than doing it in javascript? e.g. something like `<h3 id="head" class="status_<%#Eval("statusValue") %>">`. Then `.status_low {color:green;}`

Comment: What your statuses and mapped colors?

Comment: @Rhumborl That did the trick.  I wasn't aware you could string concatenate in that way within a header tag.  Can you write that up so I can mark it as an answer please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without JavaScript**

Rather than using JavaScript to change the header after it has all been rendered, it would be better to create a CSS class based on each status and then use the `statusValue` to set that class. Something like:

```
<h3 id="head" class="status_<%#Eval("statusValue") %>">
```

Then your CSS would be like:

```
.status_low {color:green;}
.status_medium {color:yellow;}
.status_high {color:red;}
```

---

**With JavaScript**

If you did need to access the status in JavaScript later for whatever reason, you would still need a similar thing but output the status as s `data-` attribute so you "store" the value with the header:

```
<h3 id="head" data-status="<%#Eval("statusValue") %>"><%#Eval("statusValue") %></h3>
```

*Rendered Output*

```js
$('h3').each(function() {
  var status = $(this).data('status');
  switch(status) {
      case 'low':
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
        break;
      case 'medium':
        $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
        break;
      case 'high':
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
        break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="head" data-status="low">low</h3>
<h3 id="head" data-status="medium">medium</h3>
<h3 id="head" data-status="high">high</h3>
```

Comment: Great solution, and also thanks for the other option above.  That my also come in handy for me!